# Repeating each item a different number of times

Tags: python, dataframe, range

I have a dataframe with a column with item names and a column with a number. I would like to create a list with the item names repeated the number of times in the column.

| item | number |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 2 |
| dog | 3 |
| parrot | 4 |

My desired output is

| item |
| --- |
| cat |
| cat |
| dog |
| dog |
| dog |
| parrot |
| parrot |
| parrot |
| parrot |

I feel like I'm quite close with this code:

```python
for index in df.iterrows():
    for x in range(2):
        print(df.item)
```

However, I can't find a way to replace 2 in range with the number out of the dataframe. df.numbers doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `df.item.repeat(df.number)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your desired output is a `list`, using @Michael's comment, you can do this:

```
list(df.item.repeat(df.number))
```

The output would be:

```
['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'parrot', 'parrot', 'parrot', 'parrot']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were keen on using `.iterrows()` then you might do something like:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"item": "cat", "number": 2},
    {"item": "dog", "number": 3},
    {"item": "parrot", "number": 4},
])

new_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_list.extend([row["item"]] * row["number"])

print(new_list)
```

This relies on the fact that `["x"] * 3 === ["x", "x", "x"]`